# Reading several large files in a loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to read several large files in a loop. So instead of doing:

```
library(fst)    
df1 <-read_fst("C:/data1.fst", c(1:2), from = 1, to = 1000)
df2 <-read_fst("C:/data2.fst", c(1:2), from = 1, to = 1000)
df3 <-read_fst("C:/data3.fst", c(1:2), from = 1, to = 1000)
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
for(i in 1:3){
df_i <- read_fst("C:/data_i.fst", c(1:2), from = 1, to = 1000)
}
```

Comment: Are all your files named data1, data2, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better using a list for the loop output like this. You can create a vector to save the dirs where the files are stored (I did on `myvec` and you can change `1:3` to `1:n` where `n` can be a larger number). With that done, all the results from loop will be in `List`. Here the code:

```
library(fst)    
#Create empty list
List <- list()
#Vector 
myvec <- paste0("C:/data",1:3,".fst")
#Loop
for(i in 1:length(myvec))
{
  List[[i]] <- read_fst(myvec[i], c(1:2), from = 1, to = 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `list.files` to generate all `.fst` files in a given dir and then loop through them:

```r
files <- list.files(pattern =".fst")  # .fst files in your current directory
df_list <- rep(list(NA), length(files)) # Init list of DFs
for (i in seq_along(files))
  df_list[[i]] <- fst::read_fst(files[i], ...)
```

- You could refine the `pattern` arg in `list.files` to match a certain pattern, e.g. `pattern = "data_\\d+.fst"` to match *data_i.fst*
- You can also specify the directory to look into via the `path` arg and return the full file names via `full.names`